# Django: How to unlink generic relation?

Tags: django, django-1.4

How to unlink generic relation?

I want to just unlink Note and Customer.

models.py

```
class Note(models.Model):
    contents = models.TextField()

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')


class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True,)
    notes = generic.GenericRelation(Note, null=True)
```

and

```
>>> cs=Customer.objects.get(pk=1)
```

```
>>> cs.notes.all()[0].delete()
```

But `cs.notes.all()[0]` is deleted fully.

I don't want delete fully. I just want unlink...

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The only "link" exists in the fact that the `content_type` and `object_id` of the `Note` object refers to the `Customer` instance. So, change those and the link goes away.